# Generate random tile within a shape

Tags: java, geometry

[image]

I'd like to get a coordinate that is within the red tiled shape. Each red tile should be equally probable to be selected.

I'm looking for is a way to visit a rectangle's tiles in an order that is random, without pre-processing any data. When visiting, I'll check if the tile is red and return that coordinate.

My naïve approach has been to randomly get an offset, then iterate from this coordinate top-left to bottom-right until a red tile is hit, but this favours the leftmost edge of the shape.

Answer (score 0):

### Stochastic method

*Selection probability by shape area*

- generate a random point within the bounding box of the red shapes
- check if that point intersects with any shape
- repeat while point does not intersect any shape

### Random shape selected

*Selection probability equal for each shape*

- determine the number of shapes (N)
- randomize the shape index to select (0..N-1)
- iterate the shapes until you reach the element with the random index